# asp.net 2.0 book recommendation?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2007, asp.net-2.0

**My background:**
1. I recently graduated college (BS in CS), and have been working full time as a MOSS 2007 software developer for 7 months. Any server side code I write is in C# using asp.net 2.0.
2. I have mostly (Java, C) experience and a strong grasp of OOP from college.

**What I'm looking for:**
A book on asp.net 2.0 that will help me understand the framework. If code examples are in C# or there is additional information on C# development, that is a plus, but my primary goal is to understand how the framework works. For example, I know that Page_Init gets called, then Page_Load, etc but how does that work internally? Any recommendations?

**Right now I'm looking at the following books:**
[Professional ASP.NET 2.0 Programmer to Programmer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0764576100), 
[Professional ASP.NET 2.0 Special Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470041781), 
[CLR via C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735621632)

Given the info above, can anyone help me limit my choices? I like the reviews for CLR via C# the best, but I'm not convinced that it will provide enough info about asp.net itself. For the other two titles, I'm wary that they assume too much knowledge of asp.net v1, but I have no such experience. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you are limiting yourself to 2.0? It was released in 2005, and is therefore a bit out of date. Can you not update your server?

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer Correct, I cannot update the server. We're also using MOSS 2007 which is based on asp.net 2.0. I'm not sure if MOSS 2007 can be upgraded to a more recent version of asp.net, but it doesn't matter since policy would prevent it anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CLR via C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735627045) is not a book about ASP.NET but it's a must for any developer working in .NET to understand it's inner workings. I say again, a must.

Either of mentioned ASP.NET books are good and provides what you need.

Comment: sorry.. what? To me that read as "It isn't a book about asp.net but its a must to understand the inner workings of asp.net". I'm assuming that you're using .NET as a synonym for asp.net here, even though they are not technically the same thing. From my understanding asp.net is a subset of .NET. Please clarify your comment. Thanks for responding.

Comment: @KyleM: I believe he is saying the book is a good reference to find out how the .NET Framework works in general (as in not specifically ASP .NET). The book probably also focuses on WinForms, Dynamic Link Libraries, etc. that you can use .NET for.

Comment: Sorry, that's what happens when you are in a conference call and responding in SO at the same time. .NET Framework != ASP.NET. In order to be a good .NET Developer you must know the .NET Framework. In order to be a good ASP.NET Dev you must know the inner workings of the page page cycle, its pipleline, how to create controls, HTTP Handler but also you need to understand how the .NET Framework works. How to deal with Exceptions, what is a App Domain, what is a delegate and so on. A great race driver not only knows how to drive, but also now the mechanics of its car.

Comment: @Markust: StackOverflow > ConferenceCalls;  =)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. I think I'll go with CLR via C# then. Appreciate the help.